# The output of multiple classes calling functions from different classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, class, reference

I am trying to understand the following code where I need to determine the output that will be printed. However, I am stuck halfway. The code (sorry I can't seem to get the spacing right):

```
# Let the classes A and B be
class A:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.i = 3
    def doubled (self):
        self.i *= 2

class B:
    def __init__ (self, an_a_object):
        self.a = an_a_object
    def put (self, an_a_object):
        self.a = an_a_object

# Further we have a program with the following statements/declarationsa
a1 = A()
b1 = B(a1)
def show (an_a_object, a_b_object):
    print '%d %d' % (an_a_object.i, a_b_object.a.i)

show(a1, b1)
b1.a.doubled()
show(a1, b1)
a2 = A()
show(a2, b1)
b1.put(a2)
show(a2, b1)
b2 = B(a1)
show(a1, b1)
b2.a.doubled()
show(a2, b2)
b1.a.doubled()
b2.put(b1.a)
show(a2, b2)
```

What will be printed by this program?

The desired output:
3 3

6 6

3 6

3 3

6 3

3 12

6 6

I understand until 6 3, but after that I don't get it. I thought b2.a.doubled() would double b2 (which I thought to be 3 before doubling, since b2 = B(a1)), but apparently b2 is 12 when doubled? And I thought a2 would be doubled as well, but a2 remains 3? Then why after the first b1.a.doubled(), both a1 and b1 are doubled (since it goes from 3 3 to 6 6)?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Also, read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. `self.a = an_a_object` does not make a copy of the `A` object. `a` and `b.a` both refer to the same *mutable* object. Changes made via one reference are visible via the other.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought b2.a.doubled() would double b2

correct.

> (which I thought to be 3 before doubling,

not correct. It is 6

> since b2 = B(a1)),

and a1 was 6, since it was doubled in line `b1.a.doubled()`

As chepner commented,

> Changes made via one reference are visible via the other.

Comment: Further a2 is only initialized via 'a2 = A()' and referenced in b1 ( 'b1.put(a2)'). None of a2 or b1 is doubled anywhere -> a2 stays 3

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why are in the first double, b1.a.doubled(), both a1 and b1 doubled, but in b2.a.doubled(), only b2 is doubled and not a2 as well?

Comment: in the first double b1 is initialized with a1 as an argument. Both a1 and b1 hold references to the same object(!). b2 is in no way related to a2 (Only by the object name, which might be confusing).

Answer (score 0):

Code with correct identation:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 3

    def doubled(self):
        self.i *= 2


class B:
    def __init__(self, an_a_object):
        self.a = an_a_object

    def put(self, an_a_object):
        self.a = an_a_object


def show(an_a_object, a_b_object):
    print '%d %d' % (an_a_object.i, a_b_object.a.i)


a1 = A()
b1 = B(a1)
show(a1, b1)
b1.a.doubled()
show(a1, b1)
a2 = A()
show(a2, b1)
b1.put(a2)
show(a2, b1)
b2 = B(a1)
show(a1, b1)
b2.a.doubled()
show(a2, b2)
b1.a.doubled()
b2.put(b1.a)
show(a2, b2)
```

Inside `class B`, `self.a` refers to the same object as created by a call to `A()`. modifiying `a` is the same as modifying `b.a` and both instances will have the same value.

This code is tricky to read due to many variables with similar names. I recomend you to use more explicative names that allow for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

It can be interesting to print all results and analyze. I changed the `__repr__` function for class A and B, so we can print them easily between each operation. I added the output between each "print" line.

```
class A:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.i = 3

    def doubled (self):
        self.i *= 2

    def __repr__ (self):
        return str(self.i)

class B:
    def __init__ (self, an_a_object):
        self.a = an_a_object

    def put (self, an_a_object):
        self.a = an_a_object

    def __repr__ (self):
        return str(self.a.i)

a1 = A()
b1 = B(a1)
a2 = None
b2 = None

def show():
    print("a1 =", a1, ", a2 =", a2, ", b1 =", b1, ", b2 =", b2)

show()
# a1 = 3 , a2 = None , b1 = 3 , b2 = None

b1.a.doubled()
show()
# a1 = 6 , a2 = None , b1 = 6 , b2 = None

a2 = A()
show()
# a1 = 6 , a2 = 3 , b1 = 6 , b2 = None

b1.put(a2)
show()
# a1 = 6 , a2 = 3 , b1 = 3 , b2 = None

b2 = B(a1)
show()
# a1 = 6 , a2 = 3 , b1 = 3 , b2 = 6

b2.a.doubled()
show()
# a1 = 12 , a2 = 3 , b1 = 3 , b2 = 12

b1.a.doubled()
show()
# a1 = 12 , a2 = 6 , b1 = 6 , b2 = 12

b2.put(b1.a)
show()
# a1 = 12 , a2 = 6 , b1 = 6 , b2 = 6
```